Laravel Passport loading public and private keys wont work with passport.php config published
I have installed and configured passport and everything seems to be working quite well until I wanted to deploy to serverless (Lambda).
I have generated my keys with artisan passport:install and published passport config from vendor.
The challenge is, after publishing the vendor config file (passport.php) and removing

Passport::loadKeysFrom('storage');

from AppServiceProvider.php
I am unable to load keys (public and private) from storage and it is because of this lines in passport.php config file

'private_key' => env('PASSPORT_PRIVATE_KEY'),
'public_key' => env('PASSPORT_PUBLIC_KEY'),

Because of these lines, laravel passport expects the keys to be set in the .env file, now I can do that and get it to work on local but when I push using ssm to load secrets from aws at deployment time as documented here https://bref.sh/docs/environment/variables, serverless fails because my serverless.yml file environmental variables content is more than 5000 bytes.
I tried using aws ssm with "composer require bref/secrets-loader" to load the secrets from ssm at runtime, I was able to deploy the code but then the server keeps responding with Service unavailable 503 error because it is taking more time to launch up since it loads ssm variables during cold starts so I figured that wont be optimal.
The best way this works out for me is to load keys in AppServiceProvider.php using

Passport::loadKeysFrom('storage');

from the storage dir but this is failing simply because I had published passport.php to config from vendor and these lines are expecting the keys from .env so Passport::loadKeysFrom('storage'); is not working.
these are the lines in passport.php causing this error and I haven't found a way around it.

'private_key' => env('PASSPORT_PRIVATE_KEY'),
'public_key' => env('PASSPORT_PUBLIC_KEY'),

I could use some guide to get passport to work on aws lambda using bref.

Ok so after looking into this over the weekend, I was able to fix this issue by loading the private and public keys in passport.php config file using file_get_content() function.

'private_key' => file_get_contents(DIR . "/../storage/oauth-private.key"),
'public_key' => file_get_contents(DIR . "/../storage/oauth-public.key"),

I hope this will help someone facing the same issue.
